# Should I include exception handling during data insertion in a database even when the data to be inserted are not given by the user?

Tags: c#, database, exception

I am writing code for an application in C#. In order to keep some sort of browsing history for each registered user, I have made a simple database in Microsoft Access. Whenever a new form is opened, a new entry is inserted in a table of the database, with the name of the active user and the name of the form.

My question is, even though what will be inserted in the database is controlled by the code written and no user input is involved, should I use exception handling just in case something goes wrong (a temporary bug or whatever else) during the insert operation in the database?

Comment: Do you want the user(s) to ever be able to convey to you that your app crashed and why?

Comment: Do you want to know that something bad happened? Do you want the user to know (do they need to know) that something bad has happened? If the former, logging the error to an event log is appropriate; if the latter, displaying the error to the user is appropriate. Either way, you should be 'handling' the error

Comment: My main concern at this point is that the app will not crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; firstly, inserting information into databases is something that could potentially fail even if your code is fine, permissions, filenames, other random bugs etc and should therefore have handling for that. Secondly, like Ňɏssa commented, adding Exception Handling for applications that will be used by people other than yourself is useful for improving your code and squashing bugs.

Comment: So I guess the same is true for reading from a database too, right? Also, what would be an appropriate exception handling message to the user in a procedure like that, which takes place behind the scenes (the user is not prompted to give input, the name of the form is silently inserted into a database)? Should I explain that the form name did not get inserted in the database or give a more general explanation?

Comment: Yes, the same applys for reading as well. The error message should generically state the issue, particularly if it happened automatically, inform them of the implications and perhaps tell them to contact you. To make bug finding easier, you could also add a diagnostics dump containing variables the code was given, the exact error and line no, etc. Something like "An error occured while recording your history, press retry to let the application try again, or quit and report the error if it persists.".